# How much novelty is there in spectral theory over Clifford algebras?

Tags: reference-request, modules, spectral-theory, matrix-decomposition, clifford-algebras

Asking here seems like the most efficient way of getting an answer. Maybe I'll get an opinion from a relevant expert.

A demonstration of my idea is to take the Takagi decomposition:

> Given a complex-symmetric matrix (i.e., one which satisfies $M = M^T$) there exists a unitary matrix $U$ and non-negative real diagonal matrix $D$ such that $M = UDU^T$.

Take note that $U^T \neq U^{-1}$, so this is not a diagonalisation of a linear map, but of a bilinear form.

What I've noticed is that if I extend the scalars to include a number $\delta$ satisfying:

$$\delta^2 = 0, \delta^* = \delta, \delta i = -i\delta$$
so that we get the algebra $\mathbb R + \mathbb Ri + \mathbb R\delta + \mathbb Ri\delta$ equipped with an involution denoted $*$. We have that:

- $M\delta$ is Hermitian when $M$ is complex-symmetric.
- From the equation $M = U D U^T$, we get $M \delta = UDU^T\delta = U(D\delta)U^*$. So $M \delta$ is unitarily diagonalisable.
- A unitary diagonalisation of $M \delta$ yields a Takagi decomposition of $M$.

I can subsequently prove the Takagi decomposition by ring restriction.

A similar trick can prove the $\mathbb R$-SVD, skew-symmetric $\mathbb C$-Takagi, and some matrix decompositions over the quaternions $\mathbb H$ and dual numbers $\mathbb R[\varepsilon]/(\varepsilon^2)$.

Is this widely known? Dare I ask whether it's at all interesting?

Comment: You might find a more useful response on MO

Comment: If you do post there also, mention on both posts you are crossposting, and include links, or else delete this post.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/2208.04272